# How to deal with user deleting a file after selecting it with <input type="file"> in HTML-Form?

Tags: javascript, html, input, file-io

I am working on a HTML-form which has an input-control of `type="file"` that I submit in an AJAX-call. All is fine and well - now a coworker came up with the challenge that a user might delete the file (from disk) that he just selected in the input-control.
Of course, no user would ever do this...but I'd like to answer his concerns.
I logged file["size"] in my AJAXSubmit-function and was surprised that it returned a value - even though the file had been deleted.
I then proceeded with `formData.append("file", file);` which seemed to work as well - and only the penultimate `xhr.send(formData);` caused an error in the console.

**Update:**
I tried (pun intended) a `Try..Catch`, but that had no effect - the error-msg is logged on the console (referring to the line that does `xhr.send(formData);`.

My next idea was to add an error-handler to xhr:

```
    xhr.onerror= function(xhr, status, error){
        console.info("xhr",xhr,"error",error,"status",status);
        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
        alert("Error while handling upload\n"+errorMessage);
    }
```

When it is called, `status`and `error`are undefined! `xhr`has a `type` element which has value `error` - and that's the best i could get. Nothing in `xhr` seems to give any indication about the problem. It seems I'll have to use error as an indicator for "error handling upload" and can't get more details. Or did I miss something?